# Create Trigger to update another table in change of value

Tags: sql, database, oracle, triggers

I have two tables TABLE_A and TABLE_B. I have a value in TABLE_A called ID. The value is updated every 30 min by a cron job. I need to create a trigger that TABLE_B stores the old and new value of ID only when IT IS CHANGED. The cron job updates the TABLE_A regardless and cannot be changed.

Example:

If the value of ID changes from 18 to 19, then it should add to TABLE_B. When it changes from 18 to 18, it should not.

I am not sure if i need to use a trigger + procedure or can only a trigger do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can code your trigger to look at the old and new values

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trigger_name
  AFTER UPDATE ON table_a
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF( :new.id != :old.id )
  THEN
    <<something changed>>
  END IF;
END;
```

If `id` can be `NULL`, you'll need a slightly more complicated condition.

Comment: +1 Since the OP is interested in UPDATE of "id" column only I would modify the second line to `AFTER UPDATE OF id ON table_a` to enhance clarity (maybe performance also?)

Comment: thanks a lot. works like a charm. :) one more question, will such a thing "for each row" work for a batch update or will it fail?

Comment: @AnujaKhemka - The trigger will fire for each row that is modified regardless of the number of rows that are changed.  If you're doing a batch update, a trigger-based solution may incur some meaningful performance overheads due to all the shifts between the SQL and PL/SQL VMs.

Comment: @JustinCave: Yes I am doing a batch update. What would you recommend for such a case in that?

Comment: @JustinCave one more thing, in case the id can be null, do i have to add special conditions to the 'if' block (like it is not null and then compare?)

Comment: @AnujaKhemka - If you're doing a batch update (depending on what "batch update" means to you and what your performance requirements are), you'd generally want the batch update process to be responsible for figuring out what data has changed (in which case it wouldn't update rows in A when there are no updates) and for the batch process to write anything you want to B.  As I said in my answer, if `id` can be `NULL`, you'd need to modify the `IF` condition to account for that.  If `id` only goes from `NULL` to `NOT NULL`, add `or (:new.id is not null and :old.id is null)`.

Comment: @JustinCave I had already used the same condition for null case as specified by you. Just wanted to make sure I am doing it correctly

Comment: @JustinCave The batch update process does not read out from the DB, it just enters all the data in a stage table which merges onto the main table. I can sure add conditions to the merge (i guess?) or read all lines out, then compare and update. I believed reading all lines out (together or doing a select based on the key), comparing and updating would be more expensive than triggers unless you have a different opinion? We want the process to be as fast as it can be.

Comment: @AnujaKhemka - I would expect that a single set-based `MERGE` from the staging table to the real table (I assume the real table is `A`) that only modified rows where there has been a change would be the most efficient approach.  Updating a row when there is no change forces Oracle to generate redo (among other things) that will slow down your load.  Of course, feel free to benchmark in your environment.